# Htaccess 301 only part of the redirect works

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi Im moving a site from one domain to another, and I have created the following .htaccess file, but its not working.

`*#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
redirect 301 http://www.el-netshop.dk/pi/Dækkape_UG150_12_lysegrå_5302_.aspx http://www.el-netsalg.dk/pi/Dækkape_UG150_12_lysegrå_5271_.aspx`

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^el-netshop.dk$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.el-netshop.dk$

RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.el-netsalg.dk/$1 [R=301,L]*

I would like it to work like this.
Have a list of urls where the url is diffent, with more then just the domain. Ex. in the above the from link contains 5302 but to link is 5271.

Then with the rest, I want it to make a normal redirect.

The above code just do (.*)$ http://www.el-netsalg.dk/$1 and ignores the special cases.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please format your code correctly, so one could read it. There seam to be missing line breaks.

Comment: Yeah, did try to format it, with the code, but it did'nt work. If you want, I can upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [apache docu](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) the syntax is as folows:

```
Redirect 301 /service http://foo2.bar.com/service
```

So try:

```
Redirect 301 /pi/Dækkape_UG150_12_lysegrå_5302_.aspx http://www.el-netsalg.dk/pi/Dækkape_UG150_12_lysegrå_5271_.aspx
```

without the "http://www.el-netshop.dk" for the old-path paramater.

Comment: Removed the http://www.el-netshop.dk but it still not working. Also Im unable to access the page without www, but thats not so important.

I uploaded my complete htaccess fil if its helps.
http://pp-nethandel.dk/test/htaccesselnetshop.txt

Comment: Try with a capital R in Redirect. I think this is important.

Comment: Thx JochenJung but its still not working :-(  Would be nice with some software to help building a working redirect.